# TypeScript call signature issue

Tags: typescript

I have file `my-module.ts`:

```
declare module "my-module" {
    interface main {
        (string):string,
        methodName():any,
        propertyName:any,
        objectName:Object
    }
    export default main;
}
```

and when using it from file `test.ts`:

```
import * as MyModule from "my-module";
var s = MyModule('test');
```

I'm getting error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

Why is it happening, and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

Following suggestion from Joe Clay, if we change the code to this:

```
declare module "my-module" {
    interface main {
        (string):string,
        methodName():any,
        propertyName:any,
        objectName:Object
    }
    var myModule: main;
    export default myModule;
}
```

And then try to use it like this:

```
import myModule from "my-module";
var s = myModule('test');
```

It generates the following JavaScript:

```
var my_module_1 = require("my-module");
var s = my_module_1["default"]('test');
```

Which throws error `my_module_1.default is not a function`.

**UPDATE**

The following change resolved the immediate problem:

```
declare module "my-module" {
    interface main {
        (string):string,
        methodName():any,
        propertyName:any,
        objectName:Object
    }
    var myModule: main;
    export = myModule; // <= Here's the change
}
```

and using it:

```
import * as myModule from "my-module";
```

However, this presented me with another problem. I showed a simplified example of `my-module`, while the real one has a few classes and `enum`-s to export. However, with the change as above we no longer can do that.

Ambient classes and `enum`-s are supposed to be exported using `export enum Name{}`, and `export class Name`, but this syntax is disallowed when `export = myModule` is used, producing error: `An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.`.

How to correct this one now? :)

Even more trouble, I have another module which has a property of type `my-module`, for which if I declare as `properName: MyModule`, i'm getting `Cannot find name 'pgMinify'`. I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) If you have a default export, the import syntax is just `import MyModule from "my-module";` - you don't need the `* as`.

b) You can't call an interface. You can call something that *implements* it, but trying to do `MyModule()` doesn't make sense.

**EDIT:**

In response to the updated code - [this is a pretty common issue when you're trying to use TypeScript's ES6 imports with a CommonJS module](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5565#issuecomment-155216760). Microsoft insist on sticking to the spec where possible, rather than using any kind of magic to convert `module.exports` to an ES6 default export - technically they're probably correct in doing so, but given that [Babel](https://babeljs.io) (probably the most popular JavaScript transpiler) does the conversion just fine, I really do wish they'd just add it to TypeScript too.

The recommended way around this is to revert your import to the `import * as MyModule from "my-module";` syntax and modify your declaration like so:

```
declare module "my-module" {
    interface main {
        (string):string,
        methodName():any,
        propertyName:any,
        objectName:Object
    }
    var myModule: main;
    export = myModule; // <= Here's the change
}
```

Hopefully that'll give you the result you're looking for.

**EDIT 2:**

It gets a little more complex when you want to start defining your own types within your declaration, rather than just primitives - but not too much more complicated. A good example to start with is [the type definitions for `body-parser`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/body-parser/body-parser.d.ts). I'm not going to copy the entire thing here, as my answer is already getting crazy long, but the things to note are:

- You can declare a `namespace`, have that as your main export, and then export other things from within that.
- It's possible to 'merge' declarations - in the file I linked, notice that they define `bodyParser` as a function, then define a namespace with the same name. These will get merged, meaning that the exports within the namespace will show up as properties of the function (e.g. `bodyParser()` and `bodyParser.json()` will both be available).

Basically, the best advice I can give you is to browse the DefinitelyTyped repository for modules you know well, and look at how their definitions were created - it's the best way to learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: That's an ambient declaration for an existing Node.js module written in JavaScript. How else should it be declared then?

Comment: @vitaly-t: You need to export something that implements your `main` interface, rather the interface itself, I think? So, something like `var myModule: main; export default myModule;`.

Comment: If I do that, the code compiles, but it generates this: `var my_module_1 = require("my-module"); var s = my_module_1["default"]('test');` which then throws with `my_module_1.default is not a function`.

Comment: @vitaly-t: I think I've seen that issue before - updated my answer.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! :) :) :)

Comment: @vitaly-t: No problem! I had the exact same issues trying to get TypeScript to play nice with Webpack, so I know the frustration all too well - glad I could help.

Comment: Would you be so kind and please follow up on the last update I provided there? I'm really stuck on that one.

Comment: @vitaly-t: Updated the answer - can't say I'm sure what's causing the very last issue you mention though!